# Can you terminate SSL to serve custom error pages, but re-encrypt before passing to the target server?

Tags: ssl, nginx, custom-error-pages, nginx-config

I have a development server that's down a lot and I'm trying to use my stable static web server to provide custom error pages on error-ed out connections. However I don't feel comfortable leaving clear-text communication going between the proxy/load-balancer and the dev server. How, or can, I decrypt and re-encrypt communications between client-proxy and proxy-devServer while intercepting any error responses?
I have a sample config, but I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding it.

```
 server {
    listen 443;

    #send to the dev server
    proxy_pass 192.168.1.2:443;

    #decrypt downstream ssl
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/frontend.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/frontend.key;

    #Serve custom error page
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    location = /custom_50x.html {
         root /var/www/errors/html;
         internal;
    }

    #Encrypt upstream communication to the dev server
    proxy_ssl  on;
    proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/backend.crt;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/backend.key;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this config file work?

Comment: Is this an Nginx stream server or http server? You seem to have bits from both.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I think that's what's confusing me. I can only find information about doing this sort of thing for stream servers, but I need to do it for an http server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nginx http server cannot pass through SSL connections (AFAIK), so you must terminate SSL at this server. An upstream SSL connection is established by using `https://` in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    #decrypt downstream ssl
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/frontend.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/frontend.key;

    location / {
        #send to the dev server
        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.2;

        # Using `https` with an IP address, you will need to provide
        # the correct hostname and certificate name to the upstream
        # server. Use `$host` if it's the same name as this server.

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
    }

    #Serve custom error page
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    location = /custom_50x.html {
        root /var/www/errors/html;
        internal;
    }    
}
```

The `proxy_ssl` directive relates to the stream server only. The `proxy_ssl_certificate` directives relate to client certificate authentication, which you may or may not require. Also, you were missing an `ssl` suffix on the `listen` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.